# Unable to send mail using spring helper classes

Tags: java, spring, email

I am having trouble sending e-mails with my gmail account using the following settings (using the springframework helper/wrapper classes):

```
JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
         sender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
         sender.setProtocol("smtp");
         sender.setPort(465);
         sender.setUsername("mylogin@gmail.com");
         sender.setPassword("my_password");

         NodeRef user = personService.getPerson(userName, false);
         String fromAddress = (String) nodeService.getProperty(user, ContentModel.PROP_EMAIL);

        // Define message
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setTo("destination@address.com");
        helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
```

Whenever I send it hangs for a while and I get the following error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
```

So far googling hasn't returned anything concrete.

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward: *Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1*. Probably you're using a wrong port, the credentials are wrong or there's a firewall that blocks the communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail's SMTP server requires TLS/SSL. You need to [setup those `Session` properties](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html#setJavaMailProperties%28java.util.Properties%29).

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // different port for tls

sender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
```

Set your username and password as you were doing.

[Here's](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en) a support page for Gmail.

Comment: Aren't they set in `sender.setHost` and other methods used by OP?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `host` maybe, but not the encryption protocols.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I had completely forgot about the encryption protocol settings. Thanks.